# Best way to keep a track of who is requesting for what data?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have got a API (on which I don't have any control) through which I am retrieving data from an external data source. The API takes a table name and a list of column names as input.

Example, Table T1 with columns C1, C2, C3 etc.

Now, I have a situation where I could have a bunch of clients requesting for data with overlapping table names and column names. For example,

> Client 1 asks for data from Table T1 and Columns C1, C2, C3
>   Client 2 asks for data from Table T1 and Columns C1, C2
>   Client 3 asks for data from Table T1 and Columns C1

I intend to maintain a map with `Table name` as the **key** and `list of columns` as **values**. Something like T1, List of (C1, C2, C3) for the above example. I would then retrieve data using the API that I have.

As I keep retrieving data, one of the client could come back and say that he is not interested in the data now. Example, C1 comes and says I don't need data for T1 and columns C1, C2, C3. But still C2 and C3 are interested and would need data & thus I still need to retrieve data for T1 and clomuns C1 and C2.

My question is: Under this scenario, what's the best way to keep a track of which client has requested for what data?

Answer (score 2):

Allow your clients specify desired output data format. And that's allow you don't worry about change of client's requirements about output column.